# Difference in definition of member and non member function prototype

Tags: c++

Am i correct, what

`typedef void(ClassName::*FunctionName)();` is definition of class member function prototype

and

`typedef void(*FunctionName)();` is definition of non class or static function prototype

And should be used differently:

For class function

pass: `RegisterFunction(&ClassName::function);`

use: `(ClassPointer->*(ClassPointer->functionPointer))()`

For static function

pass: `RegisterFunction(&function);`

use: `functionPointer();`

Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: Neither is a definition of a *function*; they're both definitions of aliases for *types*.

Comment: Sorry, i was meaning this. Thanks. updated

Comment: `(ClassPointer->*(ClassPointer->functionPointer))()` should be `(ClassPointer->*functionPointer)()`, if `functionPointer` is not a member of the class.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But it is a member in my case. It is correct?

Comment: You need to use `typedef` inside a `class` or not, just want the usage of pointer to member-data and member-function?

Comment: I want to realize difference between this two types of declaration.